# Find big files and empty them

Tags: bash, cron

will the following find big log files (over 1GB) at the /opt directory and empty them?

`find /opt/ -type f -size +1G -exec cat > /dev/null {} \;`

thank you.

Comment: Surely removing these files would make more sense than overwriting them?

Comment: or compressing them...  `find /opt/ -type f -size +1G -exec bzip2 -v {} +`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you are facing is that the redirection (`>`) is a property of the shell, whereas `cat` doesn't know anything about it.

the simplest solution for your problem is probably just putting the file-emptying into a small wrapper script (it needs to escape the `$` with backslashes, in order for the heredoc to not expand `$@` and `$f` but instead write them into the wrapper-script literally).

```sh
$ cat >/tmp/wrapper-script.sh  <<'EOL'
#!/bin/sh

for f in "$@"; do
  cat /dev/null > "${f}"
done
EOL

$ chmod +x /tmp/wrapper-script.sh

$ find /opt/ -type f -size +1G -exec /tmp/wrapper-script.sh {} +
```

the wrapper-script iterates over all files given on the cmdline and empties all of them (note the `+` specifier in the `find` invocation).

Answer (score 3):

This is what's required :

```
find /opt/ -type f -size +1G -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

The redirection in your code causes `cat` writing big files into /dev/null.

It may be safer to add a `name` clause :

```
find /opt/ -type f -name "*.log" -size +1G -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

Comment: did you mean to cp or mv?

Comment: I think OP wanted `cp`, as he may not want to remove the log file.

Comment: I don't want to remove the log file, but to empty it. Why not cat?

Comment: It is still possible with `cat`, but it's much simpler and cleaner with `cp`, maybe you can accect one of the answers ?

Comment: @user10573594 If you use `cat`, you need `>` and that is a **shell** redirection, but your `-exec` is not running in a shell. So if you wanted to use shell redirection you would need `-exec bash -c 'cat ...' \;` and then you would need to pass a parameter of the filename and it would all get ugly, and take 2 processes (`bash` and `cat`) for each file. So, `cp` is cleaner as Philippe says.

Answer (score 3):

If you have **GNU coreutils**, you can use `truncate` like this:

```
find /opt/ -type f -size +1G -exec truncate -s0 {} \;
```